# How to fix a pending transaction

Tags: ropsten

I'm using Blockcert to generate transactions.

Transaction fees are set using the default price (25.000) but, for no reasons, my transaction and my account is in "pending" and I'm not able to do anithing more.

[This is the transaction](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x84c5fd2556fd9b84f049e874801cabfb78ca626df51f02f968bedaa27b055f08) (ropsten)

What's happened?

Comment: link to empty ropsten page. probably the tx got deleted or canceled

Comment: It looks like a Blockcert issue, did you try asking them what is going on?